# How to use Queue<T> in the add method of a list

Tags: c#, queue

I have a property of:

```
public Queue<string> IncomingQueue { get; set; }
```

With a field of:

```
public Queue<string> _incomingQueue = new Queue<string>();
```

And a fully-qualified constructor for my Transponder of:

```
public Transponder(string partNumber, string description, Unit unitOfMeasure, decimal cost, decimal markup, Format encoding, string outgoingMessage, Queue<string> incomingQueue)
        : base(partNumber, description, unitOfMeasure, cost, markup)
    {
        this.Encoding = encoding;
        this.OutgoingMessage = outgoingMessage;
        this.IncomingQueue = incomingQueue;
    }
```

When I manually try to add a transponder to my communicators list, I don't know how to input the Queue incomingQueue in the add(). How do I represent the incomingQueue?
Here is my add() without the Queue:

```
inventory.Add(new Transponder(RandomTransponderPartNumber<Transponder>(), "Specific Features", Unit.each, 1000m, 125m, Format.XML, "Is anybody out there!", ));
```

Edit:
Here is the directive for the Queue:  Add Queue-string property IncomingQueue along with a corresponding private field of type Queue-string. This will receive messages from other Transponders. The default initial value should be an empty Queue.

Comment: The `IncomingQueue` property is property of *what*?

Comment: Also, the way you defined the `IncomingQueue` property, you don't need a field backing it. The compiler automatically creates backing fields for simple `getter/setters`. Let alone, even if you did want the field, you certainly wouldn't want it to be `public`. That defeats the purpose.

Comment: @mattm Is there another way to have a default incomingQueue be empty? I have been unable to figure out how to have the empty default. Thanks for pointing out the public snafu! I added clarification on the queue to the op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that last parameter when calling `inventory.Add()`, the following would initialize `Transponder` with a new, empty queue.

```
..., new Queue<string>()));
```

If you need the backing field tied to the public property, this is typically how it's done:

```
private Queue<string> _incomingQueue = new Queue<string>();
public Queue<string> IncomingQueue
{
    get { return _incomingQueue; }
    set { _incomingQueue = value; }
}
```

Note, however, that if the `IncomingQueue` property will **always** be empty to begin with, then you can just leave out that last constructor parameter, along with the corresponding `this.IncomingQueue = incomingQueue;` line inside the constructor; the private backing property `_incomingQueue` will ensure that it always starts out as an empty `Queue<string>` instance.

Comment: Apologies for the edits... as @mattm pointed out above, it wasn't immediately clear that `IncomingQueue` was a property of `Transponder`. (And even now, it's still just a guess...)

Comment: It is a good guess! I am still learning how to ask questions in this community. Sorry for the lack of clarity. For the purpose of this exercise it will always be empty. Thanks

Comment: I think asking questions well is a lot harder than answering them well! Have you seen [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the Help Center, or  [Writing the Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) from Jon Skeet's blog?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need following line of code, because the automatic property `IncomingQueue` you already have gets a backing field created by the compiler -

`public Queue<string> _incomingQueue = new Queue<string>();`

2. Looks like you want to initialize you `Transponder` class with a new incoming queue

`inventory.Add(new Transponder(RandomTransponderPartNumber<Transponder>(), "Specific Features", Unit.each, 1000m, 125m, Format.XML, "Is anybody out there!", new Queue<string>()));`